# Django user profile style auth with Djoser

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, djoser

I'm trying to implement authentication with [djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Since I haven't extended my `AbstractBaseUser` from `Django` at start of my project I decided to use a **one-to-one profile** relation pattern. I have a seperated user app and Here are my related codes:

```
# models.py (user and profile models)
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser


class User(BaseUser):
    @property
    def mobile_number(self):
        return self.profile.mobile_number


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

```
# settings.py (djoser settings)
...
DJOSER = {
    "SERIALIZERS":{
        "user": "user.serializers.UserSerializer"
        "current_user": "user.serializers.UserSerializer"
        "user_create": "user.serializers.UserCreateSerializer"
    }
    ...
}
...
```

```
# user.serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UserProfile
from .models import User
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ["user"]


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "mobile_number"]


class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):

    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)

    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ["username", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "mobile_number"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        mobile_number = validated_data.pop("mobile_number")
        user = super.create(**validated_data)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, mobile_number=mobile_number)
        return user
```

What I'm trying to do here is

1. Skip migrations with adding just a property to `django` `User` model.
2. Extending Djoser serializer to just create the relation in create step.

But when i try to create user with post request to `djoser endpoint (auth/users/create)` with body like this:

```
{
  "username": "user",
  "email": "user@examssple.com",
  "first_name": "hatef",
  "last_name": "madani",
  "mobile_number": "01236549879"
}
```

I receive this error: `"User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mobile_number'"`. Any help on current approach or better one would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow this official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/

your custom User should extends AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser and you need customize a UserManager with create_user(..) method

Comment: But this seems to makes a lot of troubles since i have some developed apps in the project and they have migrations based on the django's default auth user.